# UTF 8 and Windows 1254 charset mismatch

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

I'm using Drupal 7. And i created a block and embed this code:

```
 $contents = file_get_contents('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.html');
```

My site charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And external link charset is:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Content-Type  CONTENT=text/html;charset=windows-1254>
```

So, when get some info on external link, i have character problem (don't seen İ, ç, ş etc..)

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your block, I would create these two lines:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.html');
$contents = iconv("windows-1254" , "UTF-8" , $contents);
```

so this page's contents will be UTF-8, the same as your pages.